# how does visual studio connect to it's dependencies?

Tags: c++, dependencies, visual-studio-2013

I've been working on a huge solution written by C++ witch has lots of external dependencies, I want to know exactly why compiler needs each type of dependencies (.h or .f or any other possible formats) for building a project,
I also want to know what are the possible formats of dependencies? 
I'm using VS2013 Premium and my language is C++.
I know it's a very general question  would anyone please introduce me a reference about dependencies in C++?
your help will be very precious for me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A header file or .f file is not a dependency. Dependencies are code that you are using (a framework for example) that doesn't come bundled with the systems OS. I do not quite understand what you are asking however, if you got code in a header file, it is quite clear that you would need to include that file in your project/solution.

- Alex

Comment: well first of all i'm sorry if my question is not clear,I'm dealing with a solution that contains 27 projects related to each other, and  in each project i have some .h files(from other projects) as external dependencies,cstdio,exception,ios,map,xmemory,... actually i want to know what exactly visual studio does to build my solution, i.e if i want to use any other IDE for example CODE::BLOCKS how can I make things as same as VS? thank you so much again Alex and I'll be very grateful if you give me a reference cause I'm kinda newbie...